# Electron application shows black screen while running on windows 7 operating system

Tags: windows-7, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am totally new to electron projects. I am facing issue is black screen shows on windows 7(64bit, 2GB ram). But runs perfectly in windows 8, windows 7(64bit, 4GB ram), windows 10 systems . Anyone give solution for this issue.

Used electron version:

```
"devDependencies": 
{
"electron": "^6.0.10"
}
```

Used Windows 7 system specification:

```
Details:
Windows 7 Professional
Ram : 2.00 GB
Processor : Intel(R)Core(TM)i5 CPU M540 @2.53GHz 2.53GHz
system type : 64-bit Operating sysytem
```

Comment: install more RAM, 2GB is really the bare minimum for 64bit Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed .NET 4.7.1 or later on the Windows 7 machine?

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/19569